# My pgfplot stretches out to the far right of my latex page

Tags: pgfplots

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    view={120}{20},
    axis lines=center,  
    ticks=none,
    xmin=-2,xmax=2,ymin=-2,ymax=2, zmin=-2, zmax=2,
    xlabel=$y$,
    ylabel=$z$,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south},
]
    \addplot3 [blue, thick, samples=100, samples y=0, domain=-2:2] ({-2},{x},{-x*x});
    \addplot3 [blue, thick, samples=100, samples y=0, domain=-2:2] ({-1},{x},{-x*x});
    \addplot3 [blue, thick, samples=100, samples y=0, domain=-2:2] ({0},{x},{-x*x});
    \addplot3 [blue, thick, samples=100, samples y=0, domain=-2:2] ({1},{x},{-x*x});
    \addplot3 [blue, thick, samples=100, samples y=0, domain=-2:2] ({2},{x},{-x*x});

\end{axis} 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here is my image.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a complete answer since from my perspective the answer to

> What am I doing wrong?

is

> Nothing that I can see.

and I'd be curious to see what's the reason for this behavior. However, this post addresses

> How can I fix this?

with

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    view={120}{20},
    axis lines=center,  
    ticks=none,
    xmin=-2,xmax=2,ymin=-2,ymax=2, zmin=-2, zmax=2,
    xlabel=$y$,
    ylabel=$z$,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.east|-current axis.origin)},anchor=west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.north-|current axis.origin)},anchor=south},
]
    \addplot3 [blue, thick, samples=100, samples y=0, domain=-2:2] ({-2},{x},{-x*x});
    \addplot3 [blue, thick, samples=100, samples y=0, domain=-2:2] ({-1},{x},{-x*x});
    \addplot3 [blue, thick, samples=100, samples y=0, domain=-2:2] ({0},{x},{-x*x});
    \addplot3 [blue, thick, samples=100, samples y=0, domain=-2:2] ({1},{x},{-x*x});
    \addplot3 [blue, thick, samples=100, samples y=0, domain=-2:2] ({2},{x},{-x*x});

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked.